# How to stop handling Gestures

Tags: ios, gesture

In my app I have a tapGesture, panGesture, rotationGesture and pinchGesture.
The tapGesture is the starting point for all gestures, it shows me among other things which subview is selected.

After I entered a button to handle ImagePicker, the subview is still selected and therefore it is still handling gestures.

My question: Is there any statement to stop handling gestures?

**EDIT**

I don't need the gestureRecognizer, therefore I put them inactive:

```
panRecognizer.enabled = NO;
pinchRecognizer.enabled = NO;
rotationRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

So if I need them I want to get them work when I am handling a tapRecognizer,
but here the recognizer do not move from inactive to active.

```
[panRecognizer isEnabled];
pinchRecognizer.enabled = YES;
rotationRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

**EDIT**

My view is a ViewController and the subviews are on the imageView.
The recognizers are assigned to self.imageView.
In the first method I disenable the recognizers and in the second method I enable them

```
- (IBAction)photo: (id) sender {

    panRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    pinchRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    rotationRecognizer.enabled = NO;

    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;

    @try {

        picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Camera is not available" 
                                                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
    }
    [picker release];
}

- (IBAction)oneTap: (UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer { 
    NSLog(@"oneTap");
    float differenz = 2000;
    [panRecognizer isEnabled];
    pinchRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    rotationRecognizer.enabled = YES;

    for (UIView* const subview in array) {  
        subview.opaque = YES;
        CGPoint const point = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.imageView];

            float zwischenS = sqrt(powf(point.x - subview.frame.origin.x,2)) + sqrt(powf(point.y - subview.frame.origin.y,2));


            if (differenz > zwischenS ) {

                differenz = sqrt(powf(point.x - subview.frame.origin.x,2)) + sqrt(powf(point.y - subview.frame.origin.y,2));
                newView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
                newView = subview;

                subview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
                subview.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
                [imageView bringSubviewToFront: subview]; 
            } 
    }
}
```

What is my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is still confusing. Can you tell us something about your view hierarchy? To which views the recognizers are assigned? What is the function of the tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: look at the update below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

property `[UIGestureRecognizer enabled]`

Comment: thanks I changed it to recognizer.enabled = NO; but nothing changed

Comment: That was a correct answer to your question how to stop handling gestures. Please, update your question if this is not what you want.

Comment: your answer seems to be correct. I am working now transfering your information. Therefore you got the +1

Answer (score 2):

```
//YOU CREATE GESTURES LIKE THIS
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];

//YOU ADD THEM LIKE THIS
     [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

//AND YOU REMOVE THEM LIKE THIS
     [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

I'm not sure how you are coding things, but I hope this gives you an idea

Comment: Thank you. But to completely remove the gesture is not my target. I want to enable touch again when doing a tapGesture.

Comment: in your question, so the recognizers are perfectly working? then you disabled them but you cannot enable them again?

Comment: Yes that is right, they are working. But after disable them, they are not working anymore

Comment: probably you need to post more code. maybe you released the recognizers after you disabled them or you are enabling another instance or a new instance of the recognizer. (Same variable but different instance)

Comment: NSLog(@"oneTap"); <---- does this line print? when you try to enable it?

Comment: YES the line is printed when I try to enable the gestures